# Inequality regarding expecation of maximum of two random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $Y$ be nonnegative random variables, and $M=max(X_1, Y)$ and $N=max(X_2, Y)$.
The CDFs of each variable are $F_{X_1}, F_{X_2}, F_{Y}, F_{M},$ and $F_{N}$.

$Proposition$:

$$E[M]\geq{}E[N]$$
if and only if
$$F_{X_1}(t)\geq{}F_{X_2}(t)$$
for $t\geq{}0$

$Proof$:

CDF of $M$ is
$$F_M(m)=F_{X_1}(m)F_Y(m)$$
since $M=max(X_1, Y)<m$ if and only if $X_1<m$ and $Y<m$.
Similarly, CDF of $N$ is
$$F_N(n)=F_{X_2}(n)F_Y(n).$$
Using the fact that $E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t))dt$ for nonnegative random variable $X$ with its CDF $F_x$,
$$E[M]\geq{}E[N] \\
\Leftrightarrow{}\int_0^\infty (1-F_M(t))dt \geq{} \int_0^\infty (1-F_N(t))dt \\
\Leftrightarrow{}\int_0^\infty F_N(t)-F_M(t)dt\geq{}0 \\
\Leftrightarrow{}\int_0^\infty F_{X_2}(t)F_Y(t)-F_{X_1}(t)F_Y(t)dt\geq{}0 \\
\Leftrightarrow{}\int_0^\infty F_Y(t)[F_{X_2}(t)-F_{X_1}(t)]dt\geq{}0$$
which is true when $F_{X_1}(t)\geq{}F_{X_2}(t)$ $for$ $t\geq{}0$

Did I proved the proposition correctly?
Please give any comments on both of my proposition and proof.
References regarding this will be really helpful.
Plus, if there is any relaxed condition that satisfies the inequality $E[M]\geq{}E[N]$ please let me know!

Comment: You prove the opposite: $\int_0^\infty F_Y(t)[F_{X_2}(t)-F_{X_1}(t)]dt\geq 0$ iff $F_{X_1}(t)\leq{}F_{X_2}(t)$. And this is right statement. Are you given that $X_1,\,Y$ (and $X_2,\,Y$ too) are independent? You use independence without mentioned it.

Comment: @NCh Yes, you are right. They are independent and I had mistake! Thank you. Besides the mistakes you mentioned, does the proof looks like correct? :)